# How to get this fancier line to divide paragraphs?

Tags: symbols, sections-paragraphs

[Here](https://www.overleaf.com/articles/non-linear-optimization/crdrfgvghhkh) I found lecture notes in which the author uses the following symbol when a certain thought is finished but no new chapter or similar follows.

[image: 1]

Since the user doesn't share his source I code I wondered if there is a package or good way to produce this symbol or if the standard method is just to insert this symbol as a picture when necessary.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The requested symbol and several other similar ones are part of the package https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfornament. Below is a screenshot from the pages 20 and 21 of the manual. You see that your ornament is symbol number `88`. The manual also gives some information on the origin on those drawings.

[image]

---

Here is an actual example to achieve something similar to your example.  My understanding is that the symbol is used on points specified by the typesetter and not after every paragraph. The command `\ornamentSep` allows just this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfornament,multicol}

%The command itself does not require the package multicol, but the example below does. The command also respects the \twocolumn option
\newcommand{\ornamentSep}{\noindent\hfil{{\pgfornament[width=0.618033988749895\columnwidth,color=red]{88}}}}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}

\author{Viktor Glombik\\\ornamentSep}

\maketitle

Greetings to Berlin, Viktor.  

\ornamentSep

Aut necessitatibus rerum et ea. Aperiam nulla quibusdam neque non voluptatem. Molestiae consequuntur asperiores beatae reprehenderit. Quia ipsum aut veniam quis rerum quos aliquam modi.

\ornamentSep

Aut necessitatibus rerum et ea. Aperiam nulla quibusdam neque non voluptatem. Molestiae consequuntur asperiores beatae reprehenderit. Quia ipsum aut veniam quis rerum quos aliquam modi.

\ornamentSep

\begin{multicols}{2}
Aut necessitatibus rerum et ea. Aperiam nulla quibusdam neque non voluptatem. 

\ornamentSep

Aut necessitatibus rerum et ea. Aperiam nulla quibusdam neque non veniam voluptatem. Aperiam nulla quibusdam neque non voluptatem veniam. Molestiae consequuntur asperiores beatae veniam reprehenderit. Quia ipsum aut veniam quis rerum quos aliquam modi. 
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**A quick remark on the OP's comment of March 2019.**
The command was designed for central alignment to the text which seems like a natural decision to me. For example, the option `headsepline` of the widely used https://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script does the same. Furthermore, any element https://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script or https://ctan.org/pkg/memoir is aligned with respect to the body text, not the physical paper page, unless I am mistaken.

Many *canons of page construction* for the `twoside` option set different widths of inner and outer margins. It should be possible to modify my command to adjust the ornament central to the page (if that is what the OP wants). I currently have no idea to do it elegantly and class independently. Such a solution should honor the *binding correction,* too. But I can offer you a dirty solution: You may manually shift like in the following modification where you need to adapt the space by yourself.

```
%uses the package changepage
\newcommand{\ornamentSep}{%
\ifoddpage%
\noindent{}{\hspace{-4.10cm}\pgfornament[width=0.5\pagewidth,color=red]{88}}%
\else%
\noindent{}{\hspace{-5.65cm}\pgfornament[width=0.5\pagewidth,color=blue]{88}}%
\fi%
}
```

I still believe that this is awkward but I do not want to insult you.

Comment: @CampanIgnis How did you take such a high resolution screen shot?

Comment: @pushpen.paul Use a pdf to jpeg/png converter. Alternatively, spend very few money on very much everything, spend very much money on good computer hardware. If you love the quality of the files which TeX and its derivatives generate you are obliged to to upload high resolutions images on this site.

Comment: @CampanIgnis Is use twoside option, therefore, if the ornament has the same space to either page margin, it looks strange. How can I fix that?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I now use it as ```\newcommand{\ornamentSep}{\noindent{}{\hspace{0.25\textwidth}\pgfornament[width=0.5\textwidth,color=red]{88}}}```, which is not dependent on the ```\pagewidth```, such that if I have larger margins on the right side for example, the ornament is still centered within the text.